# Apache2 redirect domain missing slash with tonger path

Tags: apache, redirect

I try to redirect a domain (`old.com`) to a new domain (`www.new.com`)

When I type `http://old.com/test/` in a browser, I am redirected to `http://www.new.comtest/`.

Here is my configuration.
The site is served with django using mod wsgi.
Any idea?

```
// old
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName old.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.new.com
</VirtualHost>

// new without www
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName new.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.new.com
</VirtualHost>

// new with www
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.new.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / var/www/index.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle I believe that should work. The only thing I can see which is different with how I do such redirection in mod_wsgi express is that I have a trailing slash on the target:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
ServerName grumpy-old-man.com
Redirect permanent / http://www.grumpy-old-man.com:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

So try adding that trailing slash.

Also be aware you should also be using:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/index.wsgi
```

and not:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / var/www/index.wsgi
```

The target WSGI script should be an absolute path. I don't think it would be guaranteed to work if you leave the leading slash off.